# What do this error mean in Naive Bayes classifier?

Tags: python

I am new to python. Actually I have a train data which is in bag of words.It's a collection of articles. Each line of the train data is an article. It includes 2000 lines. The labels of the train data is in another file and each i label is equal to i article in the train data. I read the whole file then I did stemming on the train data and also removed the stop words. I am using NaiveBayes as a classifier, but an error occurred which I don't know how to solve. I appreciate any quick help.

My code is :

```
 import nltk
 from nltk import stem
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
 from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
 stop = stopwords.words('english')

 list_of_articles=[]
 list_of_articles_test=[]
 stemmer=stem.PorterStemmer()
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
 count_vect = CountVectorizer()
 tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()

 Label_file = open('D:\\2nd semester\\NLP1\\exercise\\data\\labels_train.txt', 'r')
 data_labels = [line.split(',') for line in Label_file.readlines()]
 with open('D:\\2nd semester\\NLP1\\exercise\\data\\data_train.txt','r') as traindata:
      for line in traindata:
           words_in_article=" ".join([stemmer.stem(w)for w in line.split() if not w in stop])
             list_of_articles.append(words_in_article)


      X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(list_of_articles)

      X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

      print(X_train_tfidf)
      print(X_train_tfidf.shape)


   Label_file_test = open('D:\\2nd semester\\NLP1\\exercise\\data\\labels_valid.txt', 'r')
   data_labels_test = [line.split(',') for line in Label_file_test.readlines()]
   with open('D:\\2nd semester\\NLP1\\exercise\\data\\data_valid.txt','r') as testdata:
              for test in testdata:
                words_in_article_test=" ".join([stemmer.stem(w)for w in test.split() if not w in stop])
                list_of_articles_test.append(words_in_article_test)
           X_test_counts =  count_vect.fit_transform(list_of_articles_test)

             X_test_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_test_counts)

             print(X_test_tfidf)
             print(X_test_tfidf.shape)


       clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, data_labels)
       predicted = clf.predict(X_test_tfidf)
       for doc, category in zip(list_of_articles_test, predicted):
            print('%r => %s' % (doc, data_labels))

       The error:
              Warning (from warnings module):
              File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 449
              y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
              DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
               Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "C:/Users/Maryam/Desktop/exercise/tfidf2.py", line 53, in <module>
               predicted = clf.predict(X_test_tfidf)
               File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 64, in predict
               jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
               File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 615, in _joint_log_likelihood
               return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T)
               File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 178, in safe_sparse_dot
ret = a * b
              File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 345, in __mul__
               raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
               ValueError: dimension mismatch
               >>>
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation of `fit_transform`?

Comment: What do you mean? How should I check it?

Comment: The [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform) have you checked them is what thefourtheye is referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X_train_counts` is a sparse co-occurrence matrix that gives you the frequency counts for all words (the columns in the matrix) in your documents (the rows in the matrix). In other words, line `(20, 5252)    1` tells you that word `5252` (the word with that index in the vocabulary) occurs once in document `20`.

However, while you have only 2000 articles, your co-occurrence matrix has many more lines. This is because you have passed the data incorrectly. Your `word_list` is simply a list of words, whereas it should be a list of articles, where each article is a string of (stemmed) words. You should do something like:

```
list_of_articles = []
for line in traindata:
    words_in_article = " ".join([stemmer.stem(w) for w in line.split() if not w in stop])
    list_of_articles.append(words_in_article) 

X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(list_of_articles)
```

As you will see, I have also adapted your check against the stop list. As it is likely that your stop list consists of words — and not stems — you should check if the words are in the stop list, and not their stems.

Comment: Thanks yvespeirsman but I met an error. I edited my question. Could you check it out, please?

Comment: Another question is that the labels are in another file. How can I match it to each article in the collection. The labels are in numbers. like the following:

Comment: like this:  1    3    2   1   0    2  3   1    .... but each in a separate line and i label refers to i article in the train data.

Comment: My mistake. `fit_transform` takes a list of strings as its argument. I have corrected the code.

Comment: As for the labels, what are you trying to do with them? If you train a classifier, it's ok to have them in a seperate list, as long as they are in the same order as your articles in the matrix.

Comment: I'm going to make a classifier. But unfortunately I don't know where to open it in my code. By the way may I have your email address?

Comment: Excuse Yvespeirsman the code is still : X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(list_of_articles)

Comment: Correct, but I changed what's inside list_of_articles in the lines above that.

Comment: yvespeirsman, I came to a dead-end in my code again. I edited my question above. Could you have a look at it?